# Headers already sent Magento On class line 1

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.7

I have error

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in path/to/file line 1
```

File where this error occurs is class file so it begins with

```
<?php
class something extends parentClass
```

I have already checked there are no spaces before line 1 i even check with HEX editor, 
there is nothing before this line.

Can someone explain what is wrong here, I'm totally lost... 
**Edit:**

The error happens when I try to redirect user after facebook login to customer edit

This happens on magento 1.7 platform...

Comment: Edit your question with more details.

Comment: [**I found this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15670400/) under **Related** >>> - [**Consult this on Stack also**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/) <= which stands at being a duplicate question.

Comment: I already check this on out, and i do not have any spaces or var_dump,echo,printf before this line

Comment: HTML, a cookie, byte order mark (<= usually a big culprit), just to name a few. Included/required files with an echo, a statement echoing an error, it could be one of 932277745 things. You can even omit certain `?>` tags which is something that has happened quite many a time before, especially with frameworks.

Comment: Have you check output buffer on or off in php.ini?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php?lq=1